# data tip in combo box

Tags: apache-flex, combobox

i use combo box to display a list of items. The box'x length is smaller whereas the items length is large. So if i mouse over it i need to display the whole item as a data tip.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of the Flex framework are you using? My general suggestion would be that you will want to implement a custom item renderer that displays tooltips in the appropriate situations. The standard Label component already has a toolTip property, so maybe you can use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if it helps:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>   <mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
> <mx:Script>
>     <![CDATA[
>         import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
>         [Bindable]
>         public var arrColl:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([{data:1,label:'item1'},{data:2,label:'item2'},{data:3,label:'item3'},{data:4,label:'item4'}]);
>         public function dataTipFunction():void{
>           comboBoxId.dropdown.showDataTips = true;
>          comboBoxId.dropdown.dataTipField = 'label';
>         }
>     ]]>
> </mx:Script>
> <mx:ComboBox x="72" y="83" id="comboBoxId" dataProvider="{arrColl}" creationComplete="dataTipFunction()" width="24">
> </mx:ComboBox>
> </mx:Application>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This feature is built into the [Flextras AutoCompleteComboBox](http://www.flextras.com/?event=ProductHome&ProductID=10) using our truncate to fit features.  To copy the text from the product page:

> The standard ComboBox will cut off the text if it is longer than the display area. You don’t get a truncation indicator. You don’t get a tooltip telling you the full text. We corrected that!

I'm pretty sure the property is named truncateToFit.  Just set AutoCompleteEnabled to false and truncateToFit to true.

If your issue is with the drop down, not the "input" portion of the ComboBox, then use the commenters suggestion of adding an itemRenderer with a Label.  The Flextras AutoComplete also includes a an 'expandDropDownToContent' property which will size the drop down to fit all the data, while keeping the 'input' portion smaller.

Free developer editions are available if you want to check it out.